# Why does light move?

Tags: special-relativity, visible-light, inertial-frames, time, observers

According to Einstein's theory of special relativity, the phenomenon known as time dilation occurs when an object is moving faster than another. The closer to the speed of light this object gets, the slower it will move in comparison to another object. The object at rest will see the other object slowing down.

So, if this happens as the object gets closer to the speed of light, what about light itself? Is it exempt from special relativity? Why can we see light move through time at all?

Comment: I think you need to define what you mean by "the slower it will move".  Since it is approaching the speed of light, you must not be referring to its velocity.  How would you expect light to "move" in this same way?

Answer (score 2):

"when an object is moving faster than another" doesn't mean anything in Special Relativity, since there is no absolute rest frame to define "faster". An object can't get "closer to the speed of light", because no matter how that object is moving (at constant velocity), light moves at $c$ in all directions, so it's always $c$ away from $c$.

Answer (score -3):

Light moves in space only. It doesn't move in time. It moves at the same speed in every reference frame, as can be seen from Minkowski diagrams in which the worldline of light always has an angle of 45 degrees (if we count the angle between the time and position axis as 90 degrees). Light has a speed of c m/sec in the frame wrt to which it moves but the clock on light itself doesn't tick. It's motion is lightlike and is exactly c m/sec through space only. If one second has ticked for an observer at rest, the light will have traveled 300 000 km. in space and 0 seconds in time. For every observer so there is no frame in which it doesn't move. Of course the clock of each observer in rest ticks and wrt to this clock light has a speed in space. Light self doesn't experience time, nor distances in space. It acts instantaneously on the matter it travels to, as seen from the light. But seen from the light itself doesn't mean seen from its rest frame as that doesn't exist. It's always on the move, for everyone. So it doesn't make sense to ask how fast light travels wrt light. Though it *does* make sense to ask how fast light travels for someone approaching the speed of light. In a sense, the instantaneous working of light is like the instantaneous working of light with infinite speed in Newtonian theory. Which makes one wonder...

Comment: "Light moves in space only. It doesn't move in time." ? A nonzero lightlike-displacement vector has a nonzero spatial-component and a nonzero temporal-component.

Comment: *the worldline of light always has an angle of 45 degrees* That means the space component has the same magnitude as the time component.

Comment: @PM2Ring But this is for the watcher only. The light moves only in space for the observer. But a clock on the photon doesn't tick. The light itself doesn't move in time nor space. What you describe I stated by the 45 degrees worldline. The light only moves for the watcher. If you Lorenz transform the frame (hyperbolic rotation) then the x and ct axis will hold their symmetric position wrt to the worldline of the light (the 45 degrees line). Of course it moves in time according to us, like it does in space. I just combined the two as the light has no restframe.

Comment: Light traces the space curvature and isn't moving in time. That's why time curvature doesn't affect it in its motion wrt us. In Newtonian mechanics, light works instantaneously. The finite c keeps cause and effect apart. The universe wouldnt function with infinite c. A new question!

Comment: Right, a photon has no rest frame, and Lorentz boosts preserve the character of spacetime intervals, so all observers agree on which intervals are timelike, which are lightlike, and which are spacelike. But an interval with a space component and zero time component is purely spacelike, so we can't describe light like that.

Comment: @PM2Ring Yes, that's true. I combine two different things. The space as seen by us and the clock tied to the photon. Still... The photon can make things happen instantaneously. We see it move in space only (if we combine our space with the photon's time). But for a photon space and time are zero, like time and space for a person moving with almost c. Of course the person has a restframe. Funny things, these photons.